# Difference between Local Policy and Registry Key

Tags: windows, windows-registry, group-policy

I would like to understand the difference between this registry key,

```
MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Netlogon\Parameters\MaximumPasswordAge=4,30
```

and the local computer policy settings via mmc,

```
Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Account Policies -> Maximum Password Age
```

why are there 2 different values, and when I change one it doesn't affect the other/

Comment: The Registry showing a value of "4, 30" is odd. That key is a REG_DWORD, which means you should only be seeing a hex value and its decimal equivalent. The Windows default is `0x0000001e (30)`. (Though, interestingly enough that does *not* match the default Local Policy value of 42.)

Comment: [Related](http://serverfault.com/q/91520)

Answer (score 1):

The first one is a [Machine Password setting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc937922), it controls the age of a silently configured 'machine password', which is used when machines connect to each other.

The second one is an Windows Password setting, which controls [User Account Passwords](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757692).

Comment: Any authoritative source for this?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about this particular case, but most of the times windows **stores** policy settings (configured in mmc) in the **registry**.